# How to compose Angular Material form control components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

The code below shows an Autocomplete form control that allows selection of a US state.

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

However, if in my application I have numerous locations where this type of input is required then it would make sense to turn this into a component (directive?) where all the boilerplate does not need to be repeated. However, I would still like to be able to use this in either template-driven or model-driven forms and allow the placeholders, validations etc. to be varied by the container component.

What is a simple and robust way to achieve this?

I have tried general approaches recommended for Angular but they do not take account of the various requirements of Angular Material. E.g. Needing to implement MatFormFieldControl. The guidance provided by Angular Material is directed more at creating a new form control using primitive elements rather than utilising/wrapping existing Angular Material form controls.

The objective is to be able to do something like this in a form:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <lookup-state placeholder="State of Residence" required="true" formControlName="resState">
    </lookup-state>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Would be very useful if those down voting could indicate why.

Comment: You can create a custom form field control: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

Comment: Thanks @masterfloda. I have tried that approach but it seems to get a little circular because the inner `input` element already has the MatInput directive already applied. i.e. there is already a control there implementing MatFormFieldControl. Do I really need to reimplement that interface? I suspect there must be a much simpler solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Agree with @PhilDegenhardt -- the custom field control approach is not well suited to wrapping form fields in components for the purpose of packaging behavior.  

Plus, I might add, the docs there are a bit ... lacking.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt, did you find a good solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Beetlejuice. No I didn't. We have vast chunks of duplicated markup scattered throughout the app and have to resort to search/replace programming when we wish to apply changes consistently. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

i'm going to paste my example of component using Angular Material. I've created a custom Input component (two cases: simple input or autocomplete):

this is my **Input.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field color="accent" [hideRequiredMarker]="true" [class.mat-form-field-invalid]="hasErrors">
  <ng-container *ngIf="autocomplete">
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [type]="type" [placeholder]="placeholder" [disabled]="isDisabled" [value]="innerValue" (input)="autocompleteHandler($event)" (blur)="autocompleteBlur($event)">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto [displayWith]="displayText" (optionSelected)="updateOption($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let choice of autocompleteChoices | async" [value]="choice">{{ choice.text }}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </ng-container>
  <input *ngIf="!autocomplete" matInput [type]="type" [placeholder]="placeholder" [disabled]="isDisabled" [value]="innerValue" (input)="inputHandler($event)" (blur)="setTouched()">
</mat-form-field>
```

this is my **Input.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent } from '@angular/material';

import { ChoiceList } from '../../../../models/choice-list';
import { ChoiceSource } from '../../../../models/choice-source';
import { getFlagAttribute } from '../../../../utils';
import { HintComponent } from '../hint/hint.component';
import { ErrorsComponent } from '../errors/errors.component';
import { FormField } from '../form-field';
import { ChoiceModel } from '../../../../models/choice-model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class InputComponent extends FormField implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() type = 'text';
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() autocomplete: ChoiceSource;

  autocompleteChoices: ChoiceList;

  @Input() set value(value: string) {
    this.innerValue = value == null ? '' : String(value);
  }
  get value() {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  @Input() set disabled(value: any) {
    this.setDisabledState(getFlagAttribute(value));
  }
  get disabled() {
    return this.isDisabled;
  }

  private changeCallback: Function;
  private touchedCallback: Function;

  isDisabled = false;
  innerValue = '';

  displayText(value: ChoiceModel): string {
    return value.text;
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (!this.autocomplete) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: Function) {
    this.changeCallback = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: Function) {
    this.touchedCallback = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  inputHandler(event: Event) {
    this.value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    if (this.changeCallback) {
      this.changeCallback(this.value);
    }
  }

  autocompleteHandler(event: Event) {
    const text = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    if (this.autocomplete) {
      if (text) {
        this.autocompleteChoices = this.autocomplete(text);
      } else if (this.changeCallback) {
        this.innerValue = '';
        this.changeCallback(null);
      }
    }
  }

  autocompleteBlur(event: Event) {
    (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value = this.innerValue;
    this.setTouched();
  }

  updateOption(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    if (this.changeCallback) {
      const { value, text } = event.option.value;
      this.value = text;
      this.changeCallback(value);
    }
  }

  setTouched() {
    if (this.touchedCallback) {
      this.touchedCallback();
    }
  }
}
```

Now i'll going to put an example of using both of them:

simple **input case**

```html
<my-input type="text" name="myInputName" [(ngModel)]="myNgModel" placeholder="---" required pattern="[a-zA-Zàèìòù\'\s0-9\.]+">
</my-input>
```

**autocomplete input case**

```js
export myClass implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewChecked {

@ViewChild('BirthTown') BirthTown: InputComponent; //from import

public autocompleteSourceBirthTown: Function;

this.autocompleteSourceBirthTown = (async function(input: string) {
      if (input.trim().length > 2) {
        const towns = await this.generalService.getListBirthTowns(input.trim());
        return towns;
      }
      return [];
    }).bind(this);
    
    // only for text of town
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.BirthTown && this.BirthTownNgModel) {
      const textTown = this.stateService.getDataBirthTown(this.BirthTownNgModel);
      if (textTown) {
        this.textBirthTown = textTown;
      }
    }
```

```html
<seg-input #BirthTown [(ngModel)]="BirthTownNgModel" placeholder="BirthTown"  [autocomplete]="autocompleteSourceBirthTown" [value]="textBirthTown" required>
</seg-input>
```

hope will help

Comment: Thanks very much @Luca. Will this work with `[formControl]` or `formControlName`? I presume this would not support adding `mat-hint`, `mat-error`, and other `mat-form-field` decorations in the containing component?

Comment: Sure will work. In my case i've not formControl, i simply use ngModel.model.control (IMHO best way, but still opinion =) ).. mat-hint, mat-error and mat-form-field are working in this example

Comment: Sorry Luca there are quite a few bits missing here (the seven imports starting with `ChoiceList`. I cannot get this to run.

Comment: every import you see that starts with `../` is one of mine. Simply `ChoiceModel` is an object with `value: any` and `Key: string`. The `ChoiceList` is an array of `ChoiceModel  --> ChoiceModel[]` and `ChoiceSource` is a method that, from a parameter (value) returns a `ChoiceList` containing that value

Comment: I did that only for having interfaces that are backend-response-like in my application. Is only for typescript, but if you run that with all types = `any` (and you know what type of object you are waiting for) it works same.

Comment: if you are satisfied please close this question =)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when wanting to create a wrapper component for an autocomplete. Below is my implementation which works in reactive and template driven forms. In order to achieve this you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor`. If you also have some validation you want to move into the component you can also implement the `Validator` interface.

I did run into an issue with the `mat-form-field` not being marked as invalid even though the form control actually was invalid. [This](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6963#issuecomment-328356344) comment on the issue "*Styles are not being applied if FormField is wrapped by a custom component*" and [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/DiQq9z0d08di1lb55oYg?p=preview) related plunker helped me fix it.

**autocomplete.component.html:**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input #input matInput type="text" class="form-control" [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete" (input)="valueChanged($event)" [readonly]="readonly"
    (focus)="$event.target.select()" (blur)="onTouched()">
  <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFunction" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
        {{ displayFunction(option) }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**autocomplete.component.ts:**

```js
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger, MatInput } from '@angular/material';
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  forwardRef,
  Injector
} from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgControl, Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { forbiddenAutocompleteValue } from 'app/shared/directives/validators/autocomplete-validator.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'pp-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutocompleteComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutocompleteComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  @Input() options: any[] = [];
  @Input() readonly = false;
  @Input() displayFunction: (value: any) => string = this.defaultDisplayFn;
  @Input() filterFunction: (value: any) => any[] = this.defaultFilterFn;

  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  @ViewChild(MatInput) matInput: MatInput;

  filteredOptions: any[];
  optionSelected = '';
  onChange = (val: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger.panelClosingActions
      .subscribe(
        e => {
          if (this.trigger.activeOption) {
            const value = this.trigger.activeOption.value;
            this.writeValue(value);
            this.onChange(value);
          }
        }
      );

    // this is needed in order for the mat-form-field to be marked as invalid when the control is invalid
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.matInput.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.options) {
      this.filterOptions(this.optionSelected);
    }
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj) {
      this.trigger.writeValue(obj);
      this.optionSelected = obj;
      this.filterOptions(obj);
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.matInput.disabled = isDisabled;
    this.trigger.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    return forbiddenAutocompleteValue()(c);
  }

  valueChanged(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.optionSelected = value;
    this.onChange(value);
    this.filterOptions(value);
  }

  onOptionSelected(event) {
    const value = event.option.value;
    this.optionSelected = value;
    this.onChange(value);
    this.filterOptions(value);
  }

  filterOptions(value) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.filterFunction(value);
  }

  private defaultFilterFn(value) {
    let name = value;

    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
      name = value.name;
    }

    return this.options.filter(
      o => o.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name ? name.toLowerCase() : '') !== -1
    );
  }

  defaultDisplayFn(value) {
    return value ? value.name : value;
  }
}
```